# GIT: command to check current branch is present in remote tracking branch

Tags: git, unix

I am trying to write one command to check if current branch is present in Remote tracking branch or not.

I got the current branch using below command: 
git branch | sed -n -e 's/^* (.*)/\1/p'

Output: master

I can get all the remote tracking branches using below command:
git show-branch -r

My question is can we have one command which will check current branch i.e. "master" is present in remote tracking branches or not?

Thanks in advance
Pritish

Comment: Why is this C++ and C?

Answer (score 2):

Store the branch name in a variable -

`export a=branch_name`

Then,

`git branch -a  | grep remotes/.*/$a`

Answer (score 1):

Using: `git branch -vv` will show present for each local branch what is the upstream branch. Something like:

```
$ git branch -vv
* master 1c33b92 [origin/master] Description
b1 1c3c81 [origin/b2] Description of b1
c1 2d4d92 Description of c1
```

Here `master` is tracking `origin/master`, `b1` is tracking remote `b2` and `c1` is just a local branch, not found remote.